# Flutter - How to spread text on a line or dynamic letter spacing bsed on width of text or container?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, row, letter-spacing

I need to implement a design whereby two text of different length on two different lines have same letter spacing.

**Example:**

```
H   E   L    L   O
H EL L O W O R L D
```

You get the picture now.

So far I have done it using a `Row` and `Row`'s `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` property. However, how can I implement it using `letterSpacing` and `maxLines=1`?

```
Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: 'HELLO'
                      .characters
                      .map((e) => Text(e,
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            fontSize: 30,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          )))
                      .toList(),
                ),
Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: 'HELLO WORLD'
                      .characters
                      .map((e) => Text(e,
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            fontSize: 30,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          )))
                      .toList(),
                ),
```

Comment: Did you test with `letterSpacing`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Yes I did, however I cannot put letter spacing dynamic it must be a fixed number. I want the letter spacing to be as much as it needs to be in the same row.

Comment: Also, maybe `spaceAround` might help. Can you include an image you are getting and an image you are expecting as result.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I want the `spaceBetween` as per design. Sorry, I cannot share the expected and current result at the moment. I have used `spaceBetween` and it works properly. 

To check my outcome use the above code and run it without overflowing. That is my result.

Answer (score -1):

> Try this

```
child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              child: Text('Hello',),

              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: The text would scale in this case. I am asking for a solution without a column or row. I have already added that solution.